# How to show local notification when app is foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, usernotifications

How to show local notification always, even in foreground, using new (from iOS 10) notification framework UserNotifications https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications?language=objc ?

Comment: add your language tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GRATERTHAN_OR_EQUALTO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

//interface
 @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@end

//implementation
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    [self registerForRemoteNotifications];
    return YES;
}

- (void)registerForRemoteNotifications {
    if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GRATERTHAN_OR_EQUALTO(@"10.0")){
        UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
        center.delegate = self;
        [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error){
             if(!error){
                 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
             }
         }];  
    }
    else {
        // Code for old versions
    }
}

////...........Handling delegate methods for UserNotifications........
//Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.

-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler{
    NSLog(@"User Info : %@",notification.request.content.userInfo);
    completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
}

//Called to let your app know which action was selected by the user for a given notification.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler{
    NSLog(@"User Info : %@",response.notification.request.content.userInfo);
    completionHandler();
}
```

May this will help you. :)

Comment: Sommm, where did you set parameter for showing notification in foreground? Because it looks like I did the same, but notifications show only in background mode. Shows meens appearing in notifications bar.

Comment: Have you used this solution before?

Comment: It shows notifications when app is in active state?

Comment: The key is in implementing willPresentNotification and calling the completion handler with a value other than "None". See [UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter?language=objc)

Answer (score -1):

```
 You can do this way.  

//in Appdelegate
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

    NSLog(@"alertbody ..%@",  notification.alertBody);
    NSLog(@"title ..%@",  notification.alertTitle);
    NSLog(@"action ..%@",  notification.alertAction);
    NSLog(@"userinfo..%@",  notification.userInfo);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"NotificationReceived" object:nil userInfo:notification.userInfo];
          });
}


//in present view controller
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(notificationReceivedMethod:) name:@"NotificationReceived" object:nil];
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
{
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:@"NotificationReceived" object:nil];
}

-(void)notificationReceivedMethod
{
//create you custom popup or view
}
```

Comment: No-no-no! I asked about UserNotification framework from iOS 10