# How to schedule a local notification in iOS 10 (objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, ios10, usernotifications

I'd like to schedule local notifications using iOS 10. I'd like to know how to do this. I've looked all around the web, but I keep finding clues only for registering and handeling the notifications. Not for the scheduling of a local notification.

So, does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Is your question about *push* notifications or *local* notifications? Your question title and the question body do not match.

Comment: @Martin R Local, I'll edit it

Comment: Did you read "Scheduling Local Notifications" in Apple's "Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide"?

Comment: I can also recommend to watch "Introduction to Notifications" from the WWDC 2016 session videos: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/707/.

Comment: i already answered it for push :(

Comment: What part of the documentation did you not understand? There's a concrete example in Apple's docs.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Try it. Its deprecated but working code. Use it for Before iOS 10.0 :

   ```
   //Get all previous noti..
    NSLog(@"scheduled notifications: --%@----", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]);

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    now = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*7]; //7 for 7th day of the week.
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

   [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit|NSTimeZoneCalendarUnit fromDate:now];


    NSDate *SetAlarmAt = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];


    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    localNotification.fireDate = SetAlarmAt;


    NSLog(@"FIRE DATE --%@----",[SetAlarmAt description]);

    localNotification.alertBody =@"Alert";

    localNotification.alertAction = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My test for Weekly alarm"];

    localNotification.userInfo = @{
                              @"alarmID":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"123"],
                              @"SOUND_TYPE":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello.mp3"]
                              };

     localNotification.repeatInterval=0; //[NSCalendar currentCalendar];


     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
   ```

   2. For iOS 10.0 and later: Now try with UserNotifications framework: Add the framework, and import like #import  . In Appdelegate Didfinishluanch method.

      ```
      UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
          [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionBadge | UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert)
                    completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                        if (!error) {
                            NSLog(@"request succeeded!");
                            [self testAlrt];
                        }
                    }];
      ```

In your ibaction or method, write it and test:

```
 NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

// NSLog(@"NSDate--before:%@",now);

now = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*7];

NSLog(@"NSDate:%@",now);

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit|NSTimeZoneCalendarUnit fromDate:now];

NSDate *todaySehri = [calendar dateFromComponents:components]; //unused



UNMutableNotificationContent *objNotificationContent = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
objNotificationContent.title = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Notification!" arguments:nil];
objNotificationContent.body = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"This is local notification message!"
                                                                    arguments:nil];
objNotificationContent.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];

/// 4. update application icon badge number
objNotificationContent.badge = @([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1);


UNCalendarNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:components repeats:NO];


UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"ten"
                                                                      content:objNotificationContent trigger:trigger];
/// 3. schedule localNotification
UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
[center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"Local Notification succeeded");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Local Notification failed");
    }
}];
```

Comment: For testing, match with your local GMT time. You can test on simulator.

Comment: Can you post the complete code? I'm not getting the alarm..

Comment: The sample is not working, the notification box doesn't appear anywhere even i sent the date to now? if there some missing code?

Comment: After setting notification , do you get your array of all notification ? Please log it. @HanzCheah

Answer (score 9):

Follow the step: 
1. Import UserNotifications.framework and go to your AppDelegate class.

In .h

```
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder          <UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@end
```

2. Register for push :

   ```
   #define SYSTEM_VERSION_GRATERTHAN_OR_EQUALTO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
   ```

Now add this in did finish launching :

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
   [self registerForRemoteNotifications];
return YES;
}

 - (void)registerForRemoteNotifications {
  if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GRATERTHAN_OR_EQUALTO(@"10.0")){
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = self;
    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error){
         if(!error){
             [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
         }
     }];  
}
else {
    // Code for old versions
}
}
```

3. Delegate methods for UserNotifications :

   ```
     //Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.

    -(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler{
   NSLog(@"User Info : %@",notification.request.content.userInfo);
   completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
   }

    //Called to let your app know which action was selected by the user for a given notification.
    -(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler{
    NSLog(@"User Info : %@",response.notification.request.content.userInfo);
     completionHandler();
     }
   ```
4. Push Notifications Entitlements : From project target’s Capabilities tab and add Push Notifications Entitlements.
   [image]
5. Add push and mobile certificate properly. Hope this is everything you need!

For more info: http://ashishkakkad.com/2016/09/push-notifications-in-ios-10-objective-c/

Comment: Okay, now the app is able to schedule the notifications. But how exactly do you schedule one?

Comment: What do mean by scheduling ? Do you want to set a local notification for some consecutive day. right ? please.

Comment: Yes, next week for example

Comment: ok. wait a few min. let me implement it please.

Comment: Your code is *identical* to the one given in http://stackoverflow.com/a/39894962/1187415. If you copy code from other resources, add a link to the source for proper attribution.

Comment: I am helped from another source martin. Thanks anyways.  @Martin R

Comment: could you share the other source @JamshedAlam ?