# What is the limit of setting number of UserNotifications at a single time for iOS 10?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, usernotifications

I have developed one application in which I have scheduled 64 local notification at a time for different fire date.

That was working perfectly for iOS less than 10.
But local notification not working correctly for iOS 10 for that I have used UserNotifications framework and scheduled 64 notifications using that which is working properly on simulator.

I am also getting all that 64 local notification on device as well.
But when I have scheduled 64 notification for iOS 10 after getting some notifications I got "XPC connection interrupted" and "No system app error" and my iOS start rebooting and application is terminated.

This error get at any time after scheduled 64 UserNotifications.

I think there is some limit to schedule number of UserNotifications at a time in iOS 10.

I have searched it but didn't get any solution.

Comment: standard limit of scheduling local notification is 64 [have a look Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1).

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216915/multiple-unusernotifications-not-firing