# How to set Alarm in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, alarm

I want to set **alarm like default CLOCK application**. I tried with `EKAlarm` but it only works like Local Notification.

My target is too wake up a person if he sleeps. Can we achieve this in iOS?

Comment: Check it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40337064/generate-local-notification-for-every-28-days-ios-10-objective-c/40337274#40337274

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set alarm like default clock application. All you can do is use `LocalNotification` and add sound to it (30 seconds max). And sound won't play if the phone in silent mode.