# Objective-C: Set timer to display a reminder using UNUserNotificationCenter

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, localnotification, unnotificationrequest

I wish to display a custom reminder or a pop up message either at the foreground or at the background of the app when it is time. I have tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39941778/how-to-schedule-a-local-notification-in-ios-10-objective-c)  but doesn't seems to work.

Nothing happened when I launch my app. It will say Local Notification succeeded but I don't see any pop up custom message box. Please help.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    //===Every 20 secs I will call setSchedule method
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20 target:self selector:@selector(setSchedule) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    return YES;
}

-(void)setSchedule{

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

    NSLog(@"NSDate:%@",now);

    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit|NSTimeZoneCalendarUnit fromDate:now];

    UNMutableNotificationContent *objNotificationContent = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];

    objNotificationContent.title = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Notification!" arguments:nil];
    objNotificationContent.body = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"This is local notification message!"                                                                   arguments:nil]; 
    objNotificationContent.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];

    /// 4. update application icon badge number
    objNotificationContent.badge = @([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1);

    UNCalendarNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:components repeats:NO];

    UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"ten"                                                                        content:objNotificationContent trigger:trigger];

    /// 3. schedule localNotification
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = self;
    [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Local Notification succeeded");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Local Notification failed");
        }
    }];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is that `UNUserNotification` not fire in foreground.

Second thing if you want to fire notification every 20 seconds or whatever time intervel then don't use `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger`.

Check below trigger method and set in your code.

```
let trigger2 = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: YourInterval, repeats: true)
```