# How to show a local notification when the user clicks a button on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

In my iOS app, I want to show a local notification when the user clicks a button.

But according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationtrigger), it looks like the notification can only be displayed:

- after a certain amount of time or on a specific date
- when the user enters or exits a specific location
- when the app gets a push notification

The best I can do so far is:

```
// content:
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.categoryIdentifier = "test_category"
content.title = "Title"
content.subtitle = "Subtitle"
content.body = "Notification body"
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

// trigger:
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 10, repeats: false)
let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

So how can I show a local notification on iOS when the user clicks a button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just make it 1 second

```
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that too but for some reason, nothing happens, I don't see any local notification. Did I miss something in my example above?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/71336816/5820010

Comment: Thanks! I tried that before but with more trials and errors, I finally managed to make it work!

Comment: @matteoh the trigger can be nil and it will trigger without delay